# ./deploy.sh not working on gitlab ci

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My problem is the bash script I created got this error **"/bin/sh: eval: line 88: ./deploy.sh: not found"** on gitlab. Below is my sample script **.gitlab-ci.yml**.

I suspect that gitlab ci is not supporting bash script.

```
image: docker:latest

variables:
  IMAGE_NAME: registry.gitlab.com/$PROJECT_OWNER/$PROJECT_NAME
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - deploy

before_script:
 - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
 - docker pull $IMAGE_NAME:$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME || true

production-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master@$PROJECT_OWNER/$PROJECT_NAME
  script:
    - echo "$PRODUCTION_DOCKER_FILE" > Dockerfile
    - docker build --cache-from $IMAGE_NAME:$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME -t $IMAGE_NAME:$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME .
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    - echo "$PEM_FILE" > deploy.pem
    - echo "$PRODUCTION_DEPLOY" > deploy.sh
    - chmod 600 deploy.pem
    - chmod 700 deploy.sh
    - ./deploy.sh
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://www.example.com
```

And this also my **deploy.sh**.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i deploy.pem ec2-user@targetIPAddress << 'ENDSSH'
 // command goes here
ENDSSH
```

All I want is to execute **deploy.sh** after docker push but unfortunately got this error about /bin/bash thingy.

I really need your help guys. I will be thankful if you can solve my problem about gitlab ci bash script got error **"/bin/sh: eval: line 88: ./deploy.sh: not found"**.

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful problem description. Please update your question to include what actually happens and what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: excessive wording

Comment: "/bin/sh: eval: line 88: ./deploy.sh: not found", I got this issue @vitr can you help me about it?

Comment: You could try running it as `- bash ./deploy.sh`

Comment: @1615903 that one you suggest is not working, same error.

Comment: Can you execute any ssh commands in the CI job?

Comment: @1615903 I got ssh: not found. How to fix this one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`docker:latest` is based on alpine linux which is very minimalistic and does not have a lot installed by default. For example, `ssh` is not available out of the box, so if you want to use ssh commands you need to install it first. In your `before_script`, add:

```
- apk update && apk add openssh
```

Answer (score 24):

This is probably related to the fact you are using Docker-in-Docker (docker:dind). Your deploy.sh is requesting /bin/bash as the script executor which is NOT present in that image.

You can test this locally on your computer with Docker:

```
docker run --rm -it docker:dind bash
```

It will report an error. So rewrite the first line of deploy.sh to

```
#!/bin/sh
```

After fixing that you will run into the problem that the previous answer is addressing: ssh is not installed either. You will need to fix that too!

Comment: In my case, the hashbang was already `#!/bin/sh`, I have to mention `- sh ./deploy.sh` to make it working.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks. This worked for me by adding **bash**

```
before_script:
  - apk update && apk add bash
```

Let me know if that still doesn't work for you.

Comment: Yup this worked for me too. The script I was trying to run required using bash to run it, but bash was not available, so it kept defaulting to `sh`

Comment: I just got bitten by this too, the error message on Gitlab's side is really vague...