# Execution of shell script fails using docker image in gitlab runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, aws-fargate

I'm following a [blogpost](https://webcaptioner.com/blog/2017/12/deploy-from-gitlab-to-aws-fargate/) on pushing docker images from GitLab to AWS Fargate. At some point there is a shell script called from the gitlab-ci.yml to login using aws cli.

I've been trying to solve this problem and in the process I've created a very minimal **.gitlab-ci.yml** to reproduce this issue:

```
image: docker:latest

stages:
- test

build_test:
  stage: test
  image: 
    name: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  environment:
    name: production
  script:
    - source script/deploy.sh
```

with the shell script (**script/deploy.sh**) being:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "preparing python installation"

apk add --update python

echo "python installed"
```

This gives the following **output on GitLab**:

```
[...]
Running on runner-fa6cab46-project-11081405-concurrent-0 via runner-fa6cab46-srm-1551436016-4b73cd2c...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/test-repo'...
Checking out 21d6f4dd as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ source script/deploy.sh
/bin/sh: script/deploy.sh: line 2: 
: not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

According to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49760256/1719618) there is likely no shell or bash in the Docker latest or dind image, but how can I solve this? I'm using the public gitlab runners.

Comment: You can try to use a different image (python for example)

Comment: Are you on a Windows host?  Does the script have Windows line endings?

Comment: @DavidMaze Ah! I feel so silly. Windows line endings turned out to be the issue indeed. Thanks. If you add an answer I'll accept it.